# how to add attributes to a XML node using StAX?

Tags: java, xml, stax

I need to generate a node in a XML file with the following structure:

```
<node attribute0="value0" attribute1="value1" > </node>
```

How can I do it in StAX?

Edit 1:
I'm trying the code from Section "3.4. Write XML File- Example" from Lars Vogel's tutorial (http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaXML/article.html)

Comment: what code have you tried? what didn't work?

Comment: why not try his more advanced tutorial as recommended in the tutorial you have tried. http://www.vogella.de/articles/RSSFeed/article.html#write_stax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

given the link you added it appears you use teh below syntax. have a look at his advanced tutorial for writting RSS feed [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/RSSFeed/article.html)

```
StartElement rssStart = eventFactory.createStartElement("", "", "rss");
eventWriter.add(rssStart);
eventWriter.add(eventFactory.createAttribute("version", "2.0"));
eventWriter.add(end);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you would use XMLStreamWriter instead of the XMLEventWriter, you can do it the following way:

```
xmlStreamWriter.writeStartElement("node");
xmlStreamWriter.writeAttribute("attribute0","value0");
xmlStreamWriter.writeAttribute("attribute1","value1");
xmlStreamWriter.writeEndElement();
```

But also for XMLEventWriter, there is a Method to create Attributes:

```
xmlEventWriter.createAttribute(name, value);
```

Regards,
Max